# creating the map with only Lidar

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, tf2, 2d-mapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using, `ROS Noetic + 20.04`.
Lidar hardware:  `rplidar_a3m1`

- I installed `slam_toolbox` package via `sudo apt install ros-noetic-slam-toolbox`and it is working fine
- I installed `rplidar driver` via [rplidar git](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros)

I want to create an indoor map using `slam_toolbox` with lidar ONLY. I do not have wheel `odometry`.

First I do,

- `roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar_a3.launch` This starts publishing on the `/scan` topic.
- `roslaunch slam_toolbox online_sync.launch` I launch the `slam_toolbox` with default config.

Initially, I encounter that map did not grow after its initialization  [#438](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/issues/438)

Then, I provided a dynamic frame as per [Broadcasting a moving frame](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28Python%29#Broadcasting_a_moving_frame). Which looks like this [tf publisher](https://github.com/amjack0/SLAM/blob/main/dynamic_tf2_broadcaster.py)

But I see my map is not generated correctly. It is moving in a circle (which I guess due to the `dynamic tf` I provided). The circle get smaller if I reduce the amplitude. I do not know what is the correct way of providing the `dynamic tf` between frames when I want to move the sensor with hand and create a map.

[image: map]

And this is how my tf tree looks like when running, `rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py`

[frames.pdf](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/files/7669864/frames.pdf)

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392423/creating-the-map-with-only-lidar/) by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2021-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on 2021-12-08**:
Try having a look at [hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam). It has worked well for me in the past.

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2021-12-08**:
@WarTurtle
Thanks for commenting.
Would you recommend `hector_slam` as better solution than `slam_toolbox`?. As `hector_slam` does not provide loop closing ability

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-12-08**:
I'm not sure that what you want to do is possible. All the SLAM algorithms I've looked at want a half-way accurate estimated robot pose for each scan they record. This value is normally constructed using measurements from sensor(s).

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2021-12-09**:
@Mike Scheutzow

I would like to generate the map of an indoor environment. I am not trying to localize the sensor, so I believe Odometry is not required. Please correct me if miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need some source of odometry information for the SLAM algorithm to work. Just laser scans is not sufficient.

Fortunately, it is possible (although not as accurate) to calculate an odometry estimate from the laser scans. Here are some packages that do this:

- http://wiki.ros.org/rf2o_laser_odometry
- http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher

Use one of these to calculate an odometry estimate and feed that into the TF tree to provide the pose of each laser scan.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2021-12-10**:
Thanks for your reply, But I suspect `laser_scan_matcher` is not a maintained repository. Although, I tried `hector_slam` and was able to localize the lidar sensor.